# WPF Telerik Create custom grid column

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I need to create custom grid column based on kendo GridViewColumn.

My xaml:

```
<telerikGrid:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding CmbContest}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn Header="TestColumn" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" ></telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn>
                <local:MultiDropDownColumn Header="SelectColumn"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDropDown, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:MultiDropDownColumn>
            </telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerikGrid:RadGridView>
```

Here is my MultiDropDownColumn class:

```
public class MultiDropDownColumn : Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewBoundColumnBase
    {               
        [BindableAttribute(true)]
        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public override FrameworkElement CreateCellElement(GridViewCell cell, object dataItem)
        {

            TextBlock tb = cell.Content as TextBlock;
            if (tb == null)
            {
                tb = new TextBlock();
            }
            tb.Text = this.SelectedItem;
            return tb;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItem",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MultiDropDownColumn),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnSelectedItemChanged));

        private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {           
        }

    }
```

Assigned Data:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<DTO> CmbContest { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {                
            CmbContest = new List<DTO>
            {
                new DTO{ Name="row1", SelectedDropDown="2"},
                new DTO{ Name="row2", SelectedDropDown="1"},
            };
        }

    }
```

When I assign data to this column, it appears empty:

[image: Empty Result]

Comment: The column itself has no DataContext. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @mm8 i want to show SelectedDropDown value in customColumn with using Custom cell view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column itself has no `DataContext`. It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do here but if you want to want to show the value of the source property in your column you should bind the `TextBlock` to it.

This requires you to store the path to the property of the source somewhere, for example in your dependency property. This displays the value:

```
public class MultiDropDownColumn : Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewDataColumn
{
    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public override FrameworkElement CreateCellElement(GridViewCell cell, object dataItem)
    {

        TextBlock tb = cell.Content as TextBlock;
        if (tb == null)
        {
            tb = new TextBlock();
        }
        tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(SelectedItem));
        return tb;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItem",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MultiDropDownColumn),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<telerikGrid:RadGridView x:Name="CmbContest" ItemsSource="{Binding CmbContest}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn Header="TestColumn" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" ></telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn>
        <local:MultiDropDownColumn Header="SelectColumn" SelectedItem="SelectedDropDown" />
    </telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerikGrid:RadGridView>
```